# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

a create relation ManyToMany beetwen my Subject table and Group table. But I have problem with "mappedBy

**Subject class :**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinTable(
    name = "ugroup_subject",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
        name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
        name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")

)
    List<Group> groups;
```

**Group class :**

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<Subject> subjects;
```

And this is my error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.tim.model.Subject.group in com.example.tim.model.Group.subjects
```

Where did I make a mistake?
Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Your property is named `groups` not `group`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo here

Change  `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "group")` to  `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")`

Comment: I was facing the simillar issue. Got error when using @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Groups"). Got fixed when changed to @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")